# Tab not recognized as an internal or external command error?

Tags: python

The code is running and inserting but I get errors in command prompt saying `'tab' is not recognised as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file`.

What is the mistake i have done and How can i fix it ?
Here is the python code :

updatedb.py

```
import sqlite3 as db
import urllib
import re
import sys
url=sys.argv[1]
htmltext=urllib.urlopen(url).read()
regex='<title>(.+?)</title>'
pattern=re.compile(regex)
title= re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
print title[0]
id="1"
conn=db.connect('insertlinks.db')
cursor=conn.cursor()
with conn:
    cursor.execute('insert into records (id,keyword) values(?,?)',(id,title[0]))
#print "inserted"
#conn.close()
```

The above code is called as follows:

```
import urlparse
import os
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="http://www.google.com"
urls=[url]
visited=[url]
try:
    while len(urls)>0:
        htmltext=urllib.urlopen(urls[0]).read()
        soup=BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
        urls.pop(0)
        for tag in soup.findAll('a',href=True):
            tag['href']=urlparse.urljoin(url,tag['href'])
            if tag['href'] not in urls and tag['href'] not in visited:
                os.system("python scraper/insertlinks.py %s"  % (tag['href']))
                os.system("python scraper/updatedb.py %s" % (tag['href']))
                urls.append(tag['href'])
                visited.append(tag['href'])
except:
    print 'error in 1'
```

EDIT:
The problem is in `tag['href']`. Its value is `http://maps.google.co.in/maps?hl=en&tab=il`. The tab in the url is creating a problem. How do i solve it?

Comment: On which line this error occurs ?

Comment: Your script is probably just missing the shebang line.  Insert `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line and retry.

Comment: How are you running this program? And what OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 8. I don't know the line where the error occurs as it continues to execute without any problems. Insertion in the database is working absolutely fine.

Comment: Don't use `os.system`. Use the `subprocess` module instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is a Windows error, not a Python error. Somehow one or both of your os.system calls are passing "tab" as a command to the Windows command line.

I suspect this is because many of the urls on the google.com page have ?tab=Wx or &tab=wT or other similar arguments tacked on to the url. The ? shouldn't hurt anything, but the & may be interpreted as the start of another command. (If that is the case, I would expect you to receive errors about a lot more than just 'tab' though.)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `subprocess.call()` method instead of `os.system()`

The & in the url is what is causing the problem.

On Windows:

```
Command1 & Command2
```

Means run Command1 then run Command2